# Get the identity of the last updated row in SQL via C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, identity

I am trying to first create a new row in my SQL Compact Edition database via C# and then I want to update the same row with information in my radiobuttons. I have an "ID" column in the database which is auto incremental.

So I tried to assign its value to a variable using @@Identity and call it in the update query but it doesn't work. I've tried MAX to find the max value in ID column which will be the latest row but it still didn't work. Here's my code.

```
con.Open();
string sqlAdd = "Insert into MembersTable ([First Name],Surname,[Middle Name])
Values('"+txtFirstName.Text+"','"+txtSurname.Text+"','"+ txtMiddleName.Text+"')";
string IDIdentifier = "Select @@Identity AS TempID";
string sqlgenderM = "Update MembersTable set Gender='M' where ID='" + DC.ID + "'";
string sqlgenderF = "Update MembersTable set Gender='F' where ID='" + DC.ID + "'";

com = new SqlCeCommand(sqlAdd, con);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlCeCommand com1 = new SqlCeCommand(IDIdentifier, con);
SqlCeDataReader dr1 = com1.ExecuteReader();
if (dr1.Read())
    {
        DC.ID = dr1["TempID"].ToString();
    }
    {
        if (rbGenderMale.Checked == true)
      {
      SqlCeCommand gendercom = new SqlCeCommand(sqlgenderM, con);
      gendercom.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }

       else if (rbGenderFemale.Checked == true)
       {
       SqlCeCommand gendercom = new SqlCeCommand(sqlgenderF, con);
       gendercom.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
      }
```

The fields (First Name, Middle Name, Surname) get updated but the Gender columns don't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you debug your code and check your program goes in to that if statements or not? Also you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also use `using` statement to dispose your database connections and commands.

Comment: It does. But it says "Update MembersTable set Gender='M' where ID='0'"

Comment: So? Your `ID` column is character typed? Why? Looks like it should be numeric typed. You get any error or exception message when you execute your update query?

Comment: The ID column is Int. I don't get any errors.

Comment: If `ID` column is `int`, you don't need to use single quotes with it. Single quotes are for characters. But it should throw error in such a case, that means your `if` statement doesn't work.

Comment: I used ID=(int)com1.ExecuteScalar();
after com1 command, but it says
'Specified cast is not valid'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Soner I used:

```
int.TryParse(dr1["TempID"].ToString(), out Identity); 
string IdentityS = Identity.ToString();
```

and replaced **DC.ID** with **IdentityS**

Now it works perfectly.